# Directory Check Won't Work

Tags: c#, directory

I tried creating a program that tells you if a directory exists or not, but no matter what I input, it always comes up as not existing.

My Code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;

class TestFileAndDirectory
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string input;
        input = Console.ReadLine();
        if ( Directory.Exists(input))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Exists");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Doesn't Exist");
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

At first I just thought maybe it was my logic, so I tried this code from the book: Microsoft Visual C# 2010: Comprehensive Ch.14:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
public class DirectoryInformation
{
   public static void Main()
   {
      string directoryName;
      string[] listOfFiles;
      Console.Write("Enter a folder >> ");
      directoryName = Console.ReadLine();
      if(Directory.Exists(directoryName))
      {
         Console.WriteLine("Directory exists, " +
            "and it contains the following:");
         listOfFiles = Directory.GetFiles(directoryName);
         for(int x = 0; x < listOfFiles.Length; ++x)
           Console.WriteLine("   {0}", listOfFiles[x]);
      }
      else
      {
         Console.WriteLine("Directory does not exist");
      }
   }
}
```

When I tried this code it did not work either not even if I put it into the same base folder as the directory I'm trying to find.

Path in question: C:\C#\Chapter.14\Cat Haikus

Path of Program: C:\C#\Chapter.14\TestFilesAndDirectories.cs

Comment: Can you give an example of your input?

Comment: My Input would be something like "Chapter.14".

Comment: And does that exist _relative to the working directory_? And does the user you are running the application as have permission to that directory?

Comment: You have to give the full path to your directory, not only the folders name. e.g. `C:\Users\theuser\Desktop\myfolder`

Comment: To Roman: I have tried that as well. To James Thorpe: Yes

Comment: Use windows explorer, go to a folder, and copy the folder name out of the address bar.  You should be able to paste it into the command prompt window using Alt+Space then e, then p

Comment: Please add the path(s) you tried to the question

Comment: @Roman No you don't - [`Directory.Exists`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists(v=vs.110).aspx) accepts a relative path too: _"The path parameter is permitted to specify relative or absolute path information. Relative path information is interpreted as relative to the current working directory."_

Comment: @JamesThorpe Yep, I noticed that directly after I've written that comment. I'm already preparing an answer using that quote from MSDN :)

Answer (score 1):

> The path parameter is permitted to specify relative or absolute path
> information. Relative path information is interpreted as relative to
> the current working directory.
>
> Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.exists(v=vs.110).aspx

If your `input` string is only a folder name like "Chapter. 14" (relative path), then this folder must exist in the path of your executable file. Like `PathOfTheExecutableFile\Chapter. 14`.

If the folder is in a completely different place, use absolute paths. Like `C:\Users\theuser\Desktop\Chapter. 14`.

**Update:**

Since you want to check `C:\C#\Chapter.14\Cat Haikus` folder, you could check if it exists using

```
if (Directory.Exists(@"C:\C#\Chapter.14\Cat Haikus")){
    Console.WriteLine("Exists");
}
```

I don't know your exact folder tree structure, but if your executable file is in a subfolder of `C:\C#\Chapter.14\`, you could also use [`Directoy.GetParent()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getparent(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

Comment: Directory I'm trying to find: C:\C#\Chapter.14\Cat Haikus


Directory of program: C:\C#\Chapter.14\TestFilesAndDirectories.cs

Comment: Can you please post the whole path of your executable file (.exe)?

Comment: If you debug the code, what is the value of your `input` string?

Comment: H:\C#\Chapter.14\TestFilesAndDirectories.cs\TestFilesAndDirectories.cs\TestFilesAndDirectories.cs  **||**  "Cat Haikus"

Comment: Well, your code works fine if I test it. You have a .exe file located in your project folders?

Comment: e.g. "H:\C#\Chapter.14\TestFilesAndDirectories.exe" or anything similar?

Comment: H:\C#\Chapter.14\TestFilesAndDirectories.cs\TestFilesAndDirectories.cs\bin\Debug\TestFilesAndDirectories.cs.vshost.exe.manifest  **||** I don't know if this count as an .exe or not but it is the only thing with that extension I could find

Comment: Well normally the .exe file is in the same folder as .vhosts.exe. Try rebuilding your solution using `Build > Rebuild Solution` in Visual Studio. And then check again your folder.

Comment: Otherwise put this line on top of your `Main` method: `Console.WriteLine(Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location));`. What is the output?